# Unity - Google Mobile Ads vs Unity-Admob

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to add ads to my game but found that there are actually two options for Android (that is, if I want to use Admob): 
There's [Google Mobile Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/sdk), and then there's [Unity-Admob](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob). Could someone tell me the difference between them and which one to use?
When trying to Google it, all I got was "Unity Ads vs Admob" and this isn't the question I'm looking for as (to my best knowledge) the two I linked should be basically the same.

Comment: To those marking this as "opinion-related": I wish to know the difference between the two as it doesn't make sense to have two separate working "admob" SDKs. The "which one to use" refers to "would both of them work, or shall I toss one in favour of the other"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there were no official plugin of admob for Unity, in earlier days.
As a result, there are multiple solutions for implementing admob in Unity android project.
However, google now provides Unity admob plugin officially. So, it is better to use that one.
Here's the link:https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

Comment: Great, that's the "GoogleMobileAds" plugin. :D I used the other but yes, I think too that going for the official is always the best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Admob Unity Plugin provides a way to integrate admob ads in Unity3D Game and u3d app. You can use it for Unity iOS and Android App with the same c# or js code.

```
https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob
```